# How to add app profile page to a existing Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, profile, facebook-page

I have a Facebook application and my app profile page has been removed by Facebook on February 1st week and now it directly goes to the application without profile page. When i tried to create a profile page by using Settings-> Advanced-> Create Fecebook Page. It shows a dialog when i clicked Confirm.

It Shows "Creating content with this name is not allowed. Try another name.". Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

go here https://developers.facebook.com/apps (while signed into facebook)

select the app you want to make a page for

click on settings on the left, 
click on the advanced section (under settings),
at the bottom of the page there is an option to create a page for your app.

Comment: Yes i have tried it. But it shows that "Creating content with this name is not allowed. Try another name." Is i need to change the app name in the basic settings ????